# Air pressure switch for balloon

Tags: sensor, switches

For a demo that I want to prepare I need a pressure switch (pressure sensor) that regulate the pressure inside the balloon.
The schema is the following: balloon inflated by an air compressor, regulated by a pressure switch (or sensor or whatever) connected to the Raspberry. So, inflate the balloon until the pressure is *n*, so the Raspberry will open the relay and shut the air compressor.

Which type of sensor can I use? I need an inline sensor or switch for the pressure and I'm not able to find it, I'm only able to find Barometrical sensor, or physical pressure sensor (touch).

Comment: This is a python example for communicating with the Honeywell ABP sensors
https://gist.github.com/quixand/7f99e5c8f9b77f10436919ee5b8ab732
please star the project if you find it useful :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use any pressure sensor which

1. <s>Uses 3.3 volts (you can use a logic-level converter)</s> Just connect the sensor to 3.3v. Usually it just works.
2. Works with whatever software your Pi is loaded with.

Take a look at a BMP085. In fact, [Adafruit even has an article all about it (how to use + sample code)](https://learn.adafruit.com/using-the-bmp085-with-raspberry-pi/overview)

Comment: How can I measure the pressure of the balloon with the BMP085?
I mean, physically, where I connect it? I think I need an inline sensor, not a BMP, or at least, I cannot see its application in my project.

Comment: @Possa Literally everything is on the link I gave you, including step-by-step instructions, sample codes, and download links.

Comment: @Possa As for the inline problem: Get a container with two and only two holes, attach sensor inside, wire up and seal off wires. Cut air hose, connect one part to a hole and another part to the second hole. If you did this then congrats. You just made a makeshift inline pressure sensor.

Comment: That's exactly the problem! I need to build that thing, or (if it exists) uses an inline sensor!
Let's suppose that this is my simplified architecture: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/P0I2OvXbcKw/hqdefault.jpg (Compressor, tube, balloon) I obviously cannot put the BMP inside the balloon, so I have to make something up!

Comment: @Possa How could a simple setup be so complicated? How could finding a container, punching holes, using hot glue and sealing off hoses be a problem? `I obviously cannot put the BMP inside the balloon` *sigh*

Comment: @Possa http://imgur.com/6CD5YEU

Comment: There is no need to be sarcastic :)
Mine was an extremization of concept, to make it easy to understand.
I get your idea the second you named it; sometimes people look in different direction an need a simple idea to get back on the right path.
It's not complicated, but it isn't my job and I haven't all the tool and material, so I have to make something up in hurry, because also time isn't on my side.
Btw, thanks for your idea, I will build it as you described to me :)

Comment: @Possa Teehee :) I hope your project goes well :D

Answer (score 0):

I have good experience with Honeywell ABPLANT005PG2A3 sensor.
[image: Honeywell sensor]

It is very small indeed (7mm x 8mm). I connect it to pressure source with SMC TIUB01 tube and M-3AU-3 fitting. I need to make only small hole with M3 thread to connect the pressure sensor.
This sensor uses 3.3V i2c so it could be directly connected to RPI pins.

It has great resolution and stability (but temperature compensation seems not to be perfect). And yes, it is cheap enough (retail price under $10).

This example shows how to work with this sensor:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <linux/i2c-dev.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>

#define MAX_PRESSURE 5.0
#define MIN_PRESSURE 0.0

#define SENSOR_ADDR 0x28

int main()
{
  int fd;
  char buf[10];
  float p, t;

  if ((fd = open("/dev/i2c-1", O_RDWR)) < 0) {
    printf("Failed to open the bus.");
    exit(1);
  }

  if (ioctl(fd, I2C_SLAVE, SENSOR_ADDR) < 0) {
    printf("Failed to acquire bus access and/or talk to slave.\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  if (read(fd, buf, 4) != 4) {
    printf("Failed to read from the i2c bus.\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  p = (buf[0] * 0x100 + buf[1] - 1638) *
      (MAX_PRESSURE - MIN_PRESSURE) / (14745 - 1638) + MIN_PRESSURE;
  t = (buf[2] * 0x100 + buf[3]) * 200.0 / 2047 / 32 - 50;

  printf("pressure=%f, temperature=%f\n", p, t);
}
```

This code should work with any i2c-enabled sensor from Honeywell (ABP series, HSC series, SSC series) as well as with some other sensors (ex. Measurement Specialties MS4515DO)